# Can I get a smaller CVPixelBufferRef when I use AVAsynchronousVideoCompositionRequest:sourceFrameByTrackID?

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation

I'm using custom `VideoCompositor` by apply `AVVideoCompositing` protocol.
I use `AVAsynchronousVideoCompositionRequest:sourceFrameByTrackID` to get a `CVPixelBufferRef`, but it looks like this function returned a origin size Image.
when I'm trying to apply a filter to it, I meet a memory issue.I assume this may because of the image size too large.

```
CVPixelBufferRef resultPixels = [request sourceFrameByTrackID:request.sourceTrackIDs[0].intValue];
CIImage *sourceImage = [CIImage imageWithCVPixelBuffer:resultPixels];
sourceImage = [self.filterComplex applyFilterComplexOnCIImage:sourceImage];
sourceImage = [sourceImage imageByApplyingOrientation:[self orientationAtTransform:simpleLayerInstruction.transform]];
sourceImage = [self scaleAndResizeCIImage:sourceImage forRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, renderSize.width, renderSize.height)];
resultPixels = [self applyFilterComplexOnCIImage:sourceImage
                                         context:self.filterRenderContext.cIContext];
[request finishWithComposedVideoFrame:resultPixels];
```

Can I get a smaller `CVPixelBufferRef` when I use `AVAsynchronousVideoCompositionRequest:sourceFrameByTrackID`
Can I resize this result `pixel` to a smaller `CVPixelBufferRef` first?
Then I can create a smaller `CIImage`.

Comment: How are you creating the `request`?

Comment: @RhythmicFistman I use AVVideoCompositing ,it provide a founcation give me a request.

`- (void)startVideoCompositionRequest:(AVAsynchronousVideoCompositionRequest *)asyncVideoCompositionRequest;`